# Why does it return undefined?

Tags: node.js, function, promise

So I have two files, `server.js` and `db.js`
Now Here is the code that I am having issue with :

```
server.js :
var DB = require('./db')
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
console.log(DB.getPostAll())
})

db.js :
MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(function (db) {
    console.log("Connected")
    var dbo = db.db('test')

    module.exports.getPostAll = function getPostAll() {
        return (
            dbo.collection('posts').find({}).toArray(function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else return res
            })
        )
    }
})
.catch(function (err) {

})
```

Sorry for the silly question. But can anyone say what am I doing wrong here ?
I am trying to use two returns. Before this I tried to use a variable in place of the returns in db.js's `getPostAll`. But it also returns `undefined`.

Comment: For part of your issue, read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of bad practices in the code, I'll try to cover some.

1. Your `db.js` file triggers an asynchronous action the moment it is required.
2. You are not returning the Promise from the `db.js` file, hence your `server.js` file starts executing code without knowing if the connection to the DB was fulfilled/pending or rejected
3. You are exporting a method after a function is executed, this leads to many odd and unexpected side effects. It is best to define all your exports at the top level of the file.

The simplest way to solve your issue is:

```
server.js :
const connectDB = require('./db')
connectDB().then((db) => {
   app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
      console.log(db.getPostAll())
   })
   app.listen(...); // lift the server ONLY when the db is connected
});

db.js :
module.exports = function connectDB() {
   return MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
   .then(function (db) {
       console.log("Connected")
       var dbo = db.db('test')
       return {
          getPostAll() {
             return dbo.collection('posts').find({}).toArray()
          }
       }
  })
}
```

In the `db.js` file, I am exporting a function that returns a promise, this way I can tell when the connection is complete (by having the promise resolved), it returns an object with all the db methods you need (`getPostAll`).

In the `server.js` file, I am waiting for the async connection to be established before I lift the app, this way I know i have my application in a ready state when it is served, and I have the `db` methods readily available for my app.

Comment: Woah That is super smart. I didn't even know it could work this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined as your promise has not resolved. Try using an async function and await your db operation to finish. See [working with async funtions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) . you can also try [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/index.html) object modeling as your mongodb client.

Comment: I see. Thanks for answer.